# How do I find out what process opened what port?

Tags: windows

I want a method of finding out what process opened what port without the aid of an external application. I.e. no netstat or other tools like it.

Comment: Check this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iphlpapi.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [IP helper functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366071%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). More specifically [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetExtendedUdpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example, for GetExtendedUdpTable, you can pass in [MIB_UDPTABLE_OWNER_PID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as the TableClass and you will be able to receive the PID of the process that issued the call to bind for the UDP endpoint.